# Strange output of a simple statespace model

Tags: control-systems

The output of statespace model seems strange.

In the follwing code, the odes are governing equations of a three floors structure, and the output are three accelerations of floors.

If I understand statespace correctly, the output is simply obtained by using C matrix and D matrix as shown in the following code.

However, the result given by statespace model is wrong.

Am I using StateSpaceModel in a wrong way?

I am not sure if I state my problem clearly, sorry for my poor English.

Thanks.

```
 Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;
\[DoubleStruckCapitalM] = {{m1, 0, 0}, {0, m2, 0}, {0, 0,  m3}}; 
\[DoubleStruckCapitalK] = {{k11, k12, k13}, {k21, k22, k23}, {k31, k32, k33}}; 
\[DoubleStruckCapitalC] = {{c11, c12, c13}, {c21, c22, c23}, {c31, c32, c33}}; 
\[DoubleStruckCapitalB]\[DoubleStruckS] = {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}; 
\[DoubleStruckX] = {{x1[t]}, {x2[t]}, {x3[t]}}; 
uvec = {{u1[t]}, {u2[t]}, {u3[t]}}; 
\[CapitalLambda] = {{1}, {1}, {1}};
lhs = \[DoubleStruckCapitalM].D[\[DoubleStruckX], {t,2}] + \[DoubleStruckCapitalC].D[\[DoubleStruckX],t] + \[DoubleStruckCapitalK].\[DoubleStruckX] // Flatten;
rhs = \[DoubleStruckCapitalB]\[DoubleStruckS].uvec - \[DoubleStruckCapitalM].\[CapitalLambda] ddxg[t] // Flatten;
eq = lhs == rhs // Thread;

\[DoubleStruckZ] = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]};
\[DoubleStruckY] = {x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]};
\[DoubleStruckU] = {u1[t], u2[t], u3[t], ddxg[t]};
ss = StateSpaceModel[eq, \[DoubleStruckZ], \[DoubleStruckU], \[DoubleStruckY], t];
{AA, BB, CC, DD} = Normal[ss];
ddxSS = CC.\[DoubleStruckZ] + DD.\[DoubleStruckU] // Flatten;
ddxEQ = {x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} /. Solve[eq, {x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]}] // Flatten;
ddxSS - ddxEQ // Simplify(*this should be {0,0,0}*)
```

[image: code picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can verify that the result from `StateSpaceModel` is correct by manually computing the transfer function and comparing it to the transfer function of the result.

```
With[{vars = LaplaceTransform[#[t], t, s] & /@ {x1, x2, x3}},
   s^2 D[vars /. Solve[LaplaceTransform[eq, t, s], vars][[1]], 
   {LaplaceTransform[#[t], t, s] & /@ {u1, u2, u3, ddxg}}]] - TransferFunctionModel[ss][s]// 
AllTrue[#, PossibleZeroQ, 2] &
```

> True

The mistake in your verification is that you are assuming that the states of `ss` are also $\mathbf{z}$. You have a descriptor system that has been converted to a standard state-space form and the original states are lost.

To preserve the original structure set the option `DescriptorStateSpace` to True. Now you can see that `eq` appears in the last state equations and the states of the descriptor state-space representation are $\left\{\text{x1}(t),\text{x1}'(t),\text{x1}''(t),\text{x2}(t),\text{x2}'(t),\text{x2}''(t
   ),\text{x3}(t),\text{x3}'(t),\text{x3}''(t)\right\}$.

```
StateSpaceModel[eq, \[DoubleStruckZ], \[DoubleStruckU], \[DoubleStruckY], t, DescriptorStateSpace -> True]
```

> [image: >]

```
eq // TableForm
```

> [image]