# Why doesn’t x’ = a.x + b.u, y = c . x + d.u hold in this state-space model?

Tags: control-systems

I have noted that sometimes state variables may change (thanks [Thomas’s help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208869/strange-output-of-a-simple-statespace-model/208888#208888)  :)), due to the Mathematica’s internal automatic transformation from a descriptor state-space model to a standard state-space model.

I think that the **relationship** `x’ = a.x + b.u, y = c . x + d.u` **should hold in any state-space**.

However, this relationship doesn’t hold in the following state-space model. 
Instead, I found that 
`x’ = a.x - b.u, y = - c . x + d.u`
hold in my state-space model. Why does this happen?

By the way, I believe that I used the right state variable in my code.

---

**`code:`**

```Mathematica
Remove["Global`*"] // Quiet;

m = {{Subscript[\[ScriptM], 1], 0, 0}, {0, Subscript[\[ScriptM], 2], 
    0}, {0, 0, Subscript[\[ScriptM], 3]}};
k = Array[Subscript[\[ScriptK], #1, #2] &, {3, 3}];
c = Array[Subscript[\[ScriptC], #1, #2] &, {3, 3}];
bs = {{1, -1, 0}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, 0, 1}};
\[CapitalLambda] = {{1, 1, 1}}\[Transpose];

uf = {uf1[t], uf2[t], uf3[t]};
ue = {ue1[t], ue2[t], ue3[t]};
pN = {pN1[t], pN2[t], pN3[t]};
mN = {mN1[t], mN2[t], mN3[t]};
u = Flatten@{uf, ue, pN, mN};
lhs = Flatten[
   m.{x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} + c.{x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]} + 
    k.{x1[t], x2[t], x3[t]}];
rhs = Flatten[+m.ue + bs.uf + m.\[CapitalLambda] pN];
eq = lhs - rhs == 0 // Thread;

y = {x1''[t], x2''[t], x3''[t]} + ue + mN;
z = {x3'[t], x3[t], x2'[t], x2[t], x1'[t], x1[t]};

ss = StateSpaceModel[eq, z, u, y, t, 
   SystemsModelLabels -> {ToString /@ u, ToString /@ y, 
     ToString /@ z}];
{AA, BB, CC, DD} = Normal[ss];
ddxEQ = Flatten[Solve[eq, {x3''[t], x2''[t], x1''[t]}]][[All, 2]];
ddxSS = (AA.z - BB.u)[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];


ddxEQ - ddxSS // Simplify
Reverse[ddxEQ] + ue + mN - Flatten[-CC.z + DD.u] // Simplify
```

---

[image: result of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue I had pointed out in an earlier [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/208888/5998).

In general, the variables you give in the second argument to `StateSpaceModel` are not the states. In this case they are $\left\{-\text{x3}'(t),-\text{x3}(t),-\text{x2}'(t),-\text{x2}(t),-\text{x1}'(t),-\text{x1}(t)\right\}$. You can determine that from the computations below.

```
states = Array[v, 6];
ssPrelim = StateSpaceModel[eq, {x3'[t], x3[t], x2'[t], x2[t], x1'[t], x1[t]}, u, 
  Join[vars = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]}, y], t];
z = states /. Solve[Thread[vars == Normal[ssPrelim][[3, 1 ;;Length@vars]].states], states][[1]]
ss = StateSpaceModel[SystemsModelDelete[ssPrelim, None, Range[6]], 
  SystemsModelLabels -> {ToString /@ u, ToString /@ y, ToString /@ z}];
```

> [image]

And then the verification works.

```
{AA, BB, CC, DD} = Normal[ss];
ddxEQ = Flatten[Solve[eq, {x3''[t], x2''[t], x1''[t]}]][[All, 2]];
ddxSS = -(AA.z + BB.u)[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
ddxEQ - ddxSS // Simplify
Reverse[ddxEQ] + ue + mN - Flatten[CC.z + DD.u] // Simplify
```

> {0, 0, 0}
>
> {0, 0, 0}

**Update**

In v12.1, the states will be the specified variables. Earlier, when possible, this worked for standard state-space systems. Now it also does so for descriptor systems.

```
ss = StateSpaceModel[eq, z, u, y, t, 
     SystemsModelLabels -> {ToString /@ u, ToString /@ y, ToString /@ z}];
{AA, BB, CC, DD} = Normal[ss];
ddxEQ = Flatten[Solve[eq, {x3''[t], x2''[t], x1''[t]}]][[All, 2]];
ddxSS = (AA.z + BB.u)[[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]];
ddxEQ - ddxSS // Simplify
Reverse[ddxEQ] + ue + mN - Flatten[CC.z + DD.u] // Simplify
```

> {0, 0, 0}
>
> {0, 0, 0}

The above calculation now works because the resulting states in fact the specified variables z.

```
states = Array[v, 6]; 
ssPrelim = StateSpaceModel[eq, z, u, 
           Join[vars = {x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x1'[t], x2'[t], x3'[t]}, y], t];
states /. Solve[Thread[vars == Normal[ssPrelim][[3, 1 ;;Length@vars]].states], states][[1]]
z
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, your answer perfectly solved my problem and greatly enhanced my understanding of state space model :)

Comment: Glad to be of help.

For a system like `StateSpaceModel[x''[t]==u[t],{x'[t],x[t]},u[t],x[t],t]`, the states are correctly ordered. I think we can do the same for descriptor systems, as the one in your example. Thanks much for your question, it has given me something to chew on.